# Image creation fails when disk_controller_type is changed to SCSI

Tags: packer

I have a working code for deploying Windows 2022 image on VMware. The existing setting for disK_controller_type is ‘lsilogic_sas’. However, if I change the controller type to SCSI and try to deploy the same code, the VM creation gets stuck at Windows installation process with an error message that is incorrect.

I tried different settings. However, the issue
persists.

disk controller type

[image]

disk configuration error

[image]

autounattend.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Size>350</Size>
                         </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Active>true</Active>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>boot</Label>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>Operating System</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows Server ${image_version} SERVERSTANDARD</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key>${windows_kms_licence}</Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OEMInformation>
                <HelpCustomized>false</HelpCustomized>
            </OEMInformation>
            <ComputerName>win${image_version}</ComputerName>
            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <RegisteredOwner/>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-ServerManager-SvrMgrNc" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon>true</DoNotOpenServerManagerAtLogon>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Description>Set PowerShell Execution Policy (64 Bit)</Description>
                    <Path>cmd.exe /c powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force"</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Description>Install Dell/EMC VMWare Tools</Description>
                    <Path>cmd.exe /c powershell -File A:\scripts\installVmWareTools.ps1</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>${os_password}</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <LogonCount>2</LogonCount>
                <Username>${os_username}</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            </AutoLogon>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Description>Set PowerShell Execution Policy (64 Bit)</Description>
                    <CommandLine>cmd.exe /c powershell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force"</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Description>Disable IPv6</Description>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters" /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 255 /f</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <Description>Initial General Server Setup</Description>
                    <CommandLine>cmd.exe /c powershell sleep 60</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>4</Order>
                    <Description>Network networkConfiguration</Description>
                    <CommandLine>cmd.exe /c powershell -File A:\scripts\networkConfiguration.ps1 -imageProduct ${image_product} -imageVersion ${image_version}</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>5</Order>
                    <Description>Initial General Server Setup</Description>
                    <CommandLine>cmd.exe /c powershell -File A:\scripts\initialGeneralServerSetup.ps1</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <Order>6</Order>
                    <Description>Reboot</Description>
                    <CommandLine>shutdown /r /t 0</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>${os_password}</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/tmp/install.wim#Windows Server ${image_version} SERVERSTANDARD" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

I tried to change the adapter type and expected it to run normally.